# Is there a name for this collection of sorted arrays data structure?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

Is there a name for the following data structure? Are there papers and citations available?

One way [to implement](https://www.nayuki.io/page/binary-array-set) an efficient **set abstract data type** is to have a collection of sorted arrays, where each array has a unique power-of-2 size.

For example, a set of 13 elements {1, 2, ..., 13} can be represented by this collection of sorted arrays: {[5], [2, 3, 9, 13], [1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12]}.

In general, the arrays that are in the collection have sizes that correspond to the 1 bits in the binary representation of the size of the set. The data structure is efficient because insertion can be performed in amortized Θ(log *n*) time, and search can be performed in Θ((log *n*)<sup>2</sup>) time (which is better than linear search). Also, it uses only Θ(log *n*) space overhead for pointers, unlike balanced binary trees and B-trees which use Θ(*n*) extra space for pointers. Thus, almost all the space is used for payload data.

I've looked at Wikipedia's [list of data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures) but didn't find a match. It's true that the book Introduction to Algorithms ("CLRS") describes this data structure as a homework problem in the "Amortized Analysis" section, but because it's a question rather than an example, the book doesn't say much about it.

Comment: I could only think of the tag "data-structures". I'd appreciate suggestions for relevant tags!

Comment: These existing questions are about the same data structure, but they ask about implementation and explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602110/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701433/ . I know how the data structure works, so I'm specifically looking for published literature about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A similar idea dates back at least to Jean Vuillemin's [original publication on binomial heaps](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359478) in the April 1978 issue of CACM. I would expect the paper that introduced this data structure to cite or be cited by Vuillemin, but none of the papers on the "references" and "cited by" lists look promising.

If I were you, I would ask [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) and then write to CLRS, but given the suboptimal bounds and lack of deletion, I don't expect anything to turn up unless the [succinct data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure) community took an interest at some point.

Is there something in particular you wanted to know?

Comment: Thanks for referencing SE:cstheory and succinct DSes, which are relevant but new to me. I asked the question because I want to write for this data structure, which I can do. But I want to give it an already accepted name, and also want to build on existing literature instead of relying on only my own ideas.

Comment: It's true that the search time is suboptimal, but I took advantage of the succinctness in one of my applications because it needed to keep millions of already-visited game states in memory. As for deletion, CLRS does say "Discuss how to implement DELETE.", but upon light thinking I can't think of any obvious way to implement it within even amortized O(n log n) time...

Comment: @NayukiMinase Come to think of it, deletion ought to be amortized O(1) as well, via the usual expedient of having bitmaps indicating undeleted items and merging a half-empty array downward.

Comment: @NayukiMinase Note that people often store game states in a Bloom filter, which trades a bit of accuracy for even more space savings.

Comment: Yup. For my game, I used a Bloom filter at the first level, and then I used this collection-of-sorted-arrays as the backing store.